# Multiplying a double by 100 in C# leads to unexpected answer

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, multiplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Maths gives wrong results!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179452/c-maths-gives-wrong-results)

I have the following code in my C# windows application project:

double test = 2.24 * 100;

If I add a watch to test, one would expect the value to be 224, however it is actually:
224.00000000000003

can anyone explain where the extra .00000000000003 comes from?

Comment: Obligatory links: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: You are multiplying doubles, not decimals (as in the title pre-edit).

Comment: Same happens to me. I'd guess some kind of rounding deviation.

Comment: Here's a program I wrote that will help you understand why 2.24 is actually not the value 2.24. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/17/looking-inside-a-double.aspx. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/floating+point+arithmetic/ (start from the bottom) if this subject interests you.

Answer (score 15):

> Multiplying a decimal by 100 in C# leads to unexpected answer

Firstly, you haven't multiplied a **decimal** - you've multiplied an IEEE 754 floating-point number by 100.

Because 2.24 does not exist as a `double`. However, if you do:

```
decimal test = 2.24M * 100;
```

it will behave as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

This is behavior by design, this is how floating point numbers work - the precision is actually limited. See [Floating Point Numbers - Accuracy Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 2):

It's a rounding error, not all numbers can be represented exactly in a `double`

Answer (score 1):

Your getting the result because 2.24 is not an exact number. There are a more significant figures beyond just the 2 you provided. I would try a multiplication by 100.00 that and then round the number using only 3 significant figures.

I should make the clarification that you need to be using a decmial variable not a double.  A double cannot represent an exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Many others have explained this already, far more eloquently than I could. Try these links on for size:

[Simple explanation](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

[Advanced explanation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

If that still leaves you scratching your head, just <insert favourite search engine> for "What every programmer should know about floating-point arithmetic"