# How do I make the sum of numbers equal to 1

Tags: c#, double

I work with probabilities and I need to check that the sum of the values is 1. I was writing unit-tests and one of the tests was failing. This is why it was failing:

```
double[] probabilities = new[] { 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 };
double sum = probabilities.Sum();
//On my PC gives sum of 0.99999999999999989

if (sum != 1)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(
        "Sum of the probabilities does not equal to 1. " +
        "Computed value was: " + sum);
}
```

What can I change to make this true: `0.4 + 0.3 + 0.2 + 0.1 = 1`?

Comment: try to edit `if (sum != 1.0)`

Comment: Another way is to use int. Multiply your probabilities by 100 (0.4 -> 40). Then you can check that `sum != 100`

Comment: @razbakov probability is usually used as a value from [0,1], so I can't use int.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Maths gives wrong results!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5179452/319403)

Comment: (Note, i'm not sure how the duplicates-marking thing works, but the question linked above is not the question i mistakenly voted as a dupe.  If you vote to close, use the link above rather than picking what i picked.  :P )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double` isn't going to give you the precision you need for that kind of math.

Switch to `decimal` and all will be fine.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - You may not want to, but if you want precise calculations with those numbers, you'll need to. The OP also doesn't make mention of any Unit Testing frameworks.

Comment: Just checked this, worked for me. Tnx! Will need to rewrite some logic

Answer (score 1):

`decimal` has the precision you want.  If you need base 10 accuracy, stick with a `decimal`.

Here is an older, but relevant article on the topic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: See also Jon Skeet's C# articles on [Binary Floating Point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [Decimal Floating Point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

almost all unit test systems have an assert that checks doubles for "closeness" That two values are within some specified tolerance.  NUnit Assert.AreEqual, for example, has an overload that takes three doubles, the actualvalue, the expected value, and the delta value, which is the maximum amount that the first two values can differ by for the Assert to pass...