# Multiplying a float rounds numbers inconsistently. How to multiply without rounding?

Tags: c#

Hi I have the function:

```
public static string MapDiePitchY(string DiePitchY)
{
    
    float value = float.Parse(DiePitchY) * 1000;
    int valInt = (int)value;
    string temp = valInt.ToString();
    return temp;
}
```

When I run it with these two numbers, I get two different behaviours:

```
str = MapDiePitchY("4150.8");
```

Returns 4150799

While

```
str = MapDiePitchY("2767.3");
```

Returns
2767300 which is what I'd expect and want everytime I pass in a float

I want the function to always return the value multiplied by 1000 but with no rounding. I've tried to replace the 1000 with 1000f and still get the behaviour where it adds extra value to 4150.8. Values that shouldn't exist there. I have no idea why this is happenign and googling hasn't given me any answers.

Is there a way to ensure I get the exact value I pass in as string but multiplied by 1000 with no rounding?

I am on C# 7.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Maths gives wrong results!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179452/c-sharp-maths-gives-wrong-results), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8967612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you understand floating-point numbers are not exact. When you type `float x = 4150.8f` the internal bit representation of the number is

```
x = (1 + 112230 * 2^(-23)) * 2^(139-127) = 4150.7998046875
```

The integers m=**112230** and e=**139** represent the mantissa and exponent of the floating-point number.

The above is the result of the parse function. Then you multiply by 1000 which results in

```
value = x*1000 = 4150799.8046875
```

what you want to do at this point *is do the rounding* before converting into an integer

```
int valInt = (int)Math.Round(value);
```

which should round up the `.80..` in the end into the next whole number `4150800`.

Comment: I inherited this code btw. Any reason one would use a float over a double or decimal?

Comment: @devn00b1090 - float is sufficient I suppose. I don't understand why numbers are stored as text though.